# How do I Change my old iPod Apple ID to my new Current ID to match the one on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, ipod-touch

About 2 almost 3 years ago I purchased an iPod touch 5. My phone and my iPod both have 2 different Apple ID's (same as 2 different email addresses). The email address used for my iPod is an email I no longer use and I'm not sure if I deactivated it or not. Anyway when I go to Settings> iCloud> it still tells me that same old email address.

Answer (score 1):

Sign in with your old Apple ID at iCloud.com, go to Settings->Manage (Apple ID)->Click on your iPod and remove it from the list of devices. And finally use your new Apple ID on your iPod.

Answer (score 0):

Contact apple directly, only they can authorise Apple ID merges or the transfer of products from one ID to another.

Use the link below to get the details. I would have my passport/ID at hand, you may also have to send them a scan of proof of purchase or proof of identity.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204169